# Pug (RIP Jade) form checkboxes - only one value returned regardless how many selected

Tags: node.js, forms, checkbox, pug

I have a form written in Pug. I am getting all the correct parameters out of the form's POST, except my checkbox array is a string containing one value - the latest day selected. Each checkbox has a name equaling an array, so the form should be returning all selected checkboxes. However, that is not happening.

Here is the relevant code in the form for the checkbox selection:

```
form#create-shift-form(action='/shifts/new', method='post')
  div.form-group
    p Select which days this shift should apply:
      div.checkbox-inline
        input.checkbox-input#create-shift-mon(type='checkbox', name='days[]', value='Mon')
        label(for='create-shift-mon') Mon
      div.checkbox-inline
        input.checkbox-input#create-shift-tue(type='checkbox', name='days[]', value='Tue')
        label(for='create-shift-tue') Tue
      div.checkbox-inline
        input.checkbox-input#create-shift-wed(type='checkbox', name='days[]', value='Wed')
        label(for='create-shift-wed') Wed
      div.checkbox-inline
        input.checkbox-input#create-shift-thur(type='checkbox', name='days[]', value='Thur')
        label(for='create-shift-thur') Thur
      div.checkbox-inline
        input.checkbox-input#create-shift-fri(type='checkbox', name='days[]', value='Fri')
        label(for='create-shift-fri') Fri
      div.checkbox-inline
        input.checkbox-input#create-shift-sat(type='checkbox', name='days[]', value='Sat')
        label(for='create-shift-sat') Sat
      div.checkbox-inline
        input.checkbox-input#create-shift-sun(type='checkbox', name='days[]', value='Sun')
        label(for='create-shift-sun') Sun
```

Why aren't all the selected checkbox values being captured in the form's POST? Why is it only returning a string of the last selected value instead of all the selected values, which is the expected HTML behavior?

If it helps, my Node/Express server is set up to parse content with the lines:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

According to [this W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/), I should just be able to give each checkbox input the same name and they will be parsed as an array of values upon POST (see example 2 in the spec). I have also tried this, which leads to the same behavior as my issue - only the last selected item is returned, and as a string, not an array.

**UPDATE**: My original setup of the code above is correct. Simply giving each attribute's `name` field the same name assembles the responses into an array. I had set up [middleware](https://github.com/analog-nico/hpp) that I had forgotten about to prevent array responses as a security measure. Removing that library, or whitelisting the route this form POSTs to, allows the original code to work without a problem.

Comment: i still dont understand fully what you are trying to achieve? the name is simply a string `days[]` its not an array and neither is evaluated in pug

Comment: Giving the name field a [] at the end should make the form return all selected values with that name[] as an array of the selected values. For some reason this isn't happening in my form. I wonder if it has to do with Pug processing of the form, but I really have no idea. Here's an example I pulled from a quick Google search to illustrate: https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2014/submit-an-array-with-a-html-form/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research here is what i found:

This method of passing an array highly depends on the server, how it will understand the data payload, PHP understands this syntax but JSON objects have it quiet differently.

```
form#create-shift-form(action='/shifts/new', method='post')
  div.form-group
    p Select which days this shift should apply:
      each val, index in ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
        div.checkbox-inline
          input.checkbox-input(type='checkbox', name=`days[${index}]`, value=val, id=`create-shift-${val}`)
          label(for=`create-shift-${val}`)=val
```

This will payload will be equivalent to something like this:

```
days[0]=Mon
days[1]=Tue
days[2]=Wed
days[3]=Thur
days[4]=Fri
days[5]=Sat
days[6]=Sun
```

which is equivalent to this payload in json:

```
{
   days: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
}
```

Source: https://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/

## Update:

For future reference:
OP figure the issue, the solution `(days[${index}])` is correct, however express body parser `extended:true` uses `querystring` instead of `qs`.

With `extended:false`, the JSON works as expected to behave. The payload becomes `"days[0]"="Mon", "day[1]"="Tues", etc.`

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }); //instead of true
```

Comment: I replaced my code with the above suggestion, however I am still only retrieving the last selected item as a string, not an array of the items. I get
`{ "days":"Thur" }`

Comment: My Node/Express server is set up with the lines:
`app.use(bodyParser.json());`
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: @eugene1832 i updated the code to have one name and different values, it should work now. tell me the results :)

Comment: No, I've already tried that! It definitely should work, but it's not. I'm not sure where I should be looking to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: @eugene1832 the problem is not from pug though, its probably something else you havent mentioned here, maybe you can create a small project with just this code inside, get it to work and see the differences.

Comment: Ah - I figured out my problem. Your original solution (`days[${index}]`) is correct. Add an additional line to replace `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });` with `extended: false`. This switches bodyParser's parsing library from `qs` to `querystring`, which then behaves as we are expecting JSON parsing to behave. I get `"days[0]"="Mon", "day[1]"="Tues", etc.`

Comment: Once you revert your answer and add the information about bodyParser, I will mark your solution as correct.

Comment: @eugene1832 thats great information! i updated the answer after reverting to include your findings for future generations :P haha